# SQL Server : generate all unique combination of an array of strings in one columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script that will generate all possible combinations of `r` elements in a given array of size `n`.

I have a C# script that can do that but I was wondering: how can I achieve the same result with a script in 1 table in SQL Server?

Example of my code:

```
        char []arr = {'1', '2', '3', 'A', 'B', 'C'};
        int r = 4;
        int n = arr.Length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
```

I'll get in return something similar to this :

```
123A
123B
123C
12AB
12AC
12BC
13AB
13AC
13BC
1ABC
23AB
23AC
23BC
2ABC
3ABC
```

All unique.

My table is simple with 2 columns - here's the create query:

```
create table Code
(
    id int primary key not null identity(1,1),
    Code varchar(10),
);
```

I want to populate the columns code with all combination of size r=4 with the given string array of all alphanumeric characters [A-Z-0-9].

Comment: Do you mean MySql, or SQL Server? Because there is **no such thing as MySQL Server**. These are two very different products, and they happen to have different answers to this problem, where the best answer is a recursive CTE and while any supported SQL Server version can do this, it's only available in very recent versions of MySql

Comment: *"SQL SERVER generate"* in the title, your question ending in *"on MySQL Server ??"* and the tags [[tag:mysql]], [[tag:sql-server]] (with [[tag:ssms]]) makes it completely unclear what RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: Remove the c# code and instead add a sample of your table that you want to query against with sample data. Ideally, the same sample data that could be used to recreate your desired output.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  sorry for the confusion, I just correct everything 
I'm talking about SQL server, I'm currently using SQL server Management Studio 2014 (SSMS)

Comment: @lptr Thanks for the exemple
How do you insert all generated value into the Code columns of my exemple

Comment: Okay. SQL Server is good. But telling us SSMS is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's name you see on the dashboard radio. It'd be okay for some people, but alarming from someone who works as an auto mechanic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross-join a CTE of your values four times

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) v(YourValue)
)
INSERT Code (Code)
SELECT CONCAT(a.YourValue, b.YourValue, c.YourValue, d.YourValue)
FROM cte a
CROSS JOIN cte b
CROSS JOIN cte c
CROSS JOIN cte d;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fd64bc47cdbaaef698f613ae47c4cf24)

There are other ways of generating your values, such as using a numbers table and `CHAR()`.

As a side note: why bother with an `IDENTITY` column? Why not just make `Code` the primary key, and make it `char(4)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,
Short and concise, 
The reason behind the Identity column was to be able to track all the codes easily based on their position in the db, then edit the same row in other columns if necessary